# AppleScript: Path to Current Application

Tags: macos, applescript

Quick question. I'm trying to get the path to the current application using AppleScript (a Cocoa AppleScript app). Basically, I'm trying to determine where the app is located so that I can manipulate a file that is within a folder in the disk image with the app. I was wondering if there is a more straightforward way of returning the path, I currently have:

```
set Var1 to (path to current application as text) & "Resources:File.xml"
```

Which returns: "Macintosh HD:Applications:Utilities:Script Editor.app:Resources:File.xml"

That's fine, except that I want to omit the name of the app in the path. I know I can do this with some text manipulation, but I have to assume there is a cleaner way other than cutting it up in to parts. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want a resulting string that looks like  `"Macintosh HD:Applications:Utilities:Resources:File.xml"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN short, not possible :( Sorry to burst your bubble. If you look a the Dictionary of the App, you'll see that it inherits from Application.

Fire up the Apple Script editor and have a look at:

```
File > Open Dictionary > Whatever Your App Is Called
```

So you're going to have to deal with basic manipulation.

Comment: Thanks. Oh well, no big deal, I'll just do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Script Editor

```
tell application "Finder"
set current_path0 to container of (path to me) as alias
end tell
set current_path1 to quoted form of (POSIX path of current_path0)
```

this should return somthing simlar to

```
"'/Users/YourUsername/Library/Autosave Information/'"
```

which stored as a variable is

```
'/Users/YourUsername/Library/Autosave Information/'
```

also if you want to be fancy try this one

```
tell application "Finder"
set current_path0 to container of (path to me) as alias
end tell
set current_path1 to quoted form of (POSIX path of current_path0)
tell application "System Events" 
display alert current_path1
end tell
```

which results in an alert box with the info as the variable format that looks something like this

```
'/Users/YourUsername/Library/Autosave Information/'
```

to get the dir of the app this script is in save this as an app and store it anywhere it will find the root of where the app is then you simply enter the app name manually i used another script to store the app name to call a file in the app's Resources Folder

```
    tell application "Finder"
set current_path0 to container of (path to me) as alias
end tell
set current_path1 to quoted form of (POSIX path of current_path0)
tell application "System Events" 
display alert current_path1
end tell
set current_path2 to text 1 thru -2 of current_path1
set appName to "Example.app'"
set AppFromRoot to current_path2 & appName
```

which returns something similar to this

```
"'/Users/YourUsername/Library/Autosave Information/Example.app'"
```

which stored as a Variable looks like this

```
'/Users/YourUsername/Library/Autosave Information/Example.app'
```

You must Define the variable AppFromRoot as your App name you want to go into in the root directory of this file or you can use this script in a different script app to make it a variable and such just depends on what your using it for